# Unable to open InternetExplorer using webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I get this error when trying to browse a url in internet explorer 11, in a windows 7 64-bit PC.

```
IWebDriver NewDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver("D:\\"); //IEDriverServer(64bit) is saved in D:\
NewDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
NewDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
IWait<IWebDriver> wait1 = new WebDriverWait(NewDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.00));

//ERROR AT THIS LINE
wait1.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)NewDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState;").Equals("complete"));
```

> ERROR : javaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

I have set all the Security regions in IE security options, to 'Enable Protected Mode' and also uninstalled the windows update 'KB3025390'. When debugging, I see the google page being loaded.

The same code works fine for FirefoxDriver.

Comment: You are disappointed in your ability to set IE conf or write readable code or use selenium or all of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of something more reasonable:

```
//Nuget install:
//PM > Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
//PM > Install-Package Selenium.Support
//PM > Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    //get will deal with page ready wait, unless it is ajax page. If you choose to do 
    //nothing then browser will close after navigation has completed          
}
```

---

Example of what "login" would look like in selenium:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("user")).SendKeys("username"); //fill in username
driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys("password"); //fill in password 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).Submit();             //submit form where element is
```

Comment: The reason I had `IWait<IWebDriver> wait1 ` was that a page might take time to load,as I have to take a screenshot of it. So, will this approach work for IE as well as other browsers

Comment: Before you ask "how to take cross browser screen area/fullpage sceenshot with selenium" check if someone has already asked about it. I remember that chrome/firefox had a few gotcha's.